# Python Spark Streaming only runs once

Tags: python, spark-streaming

I've been working on some Spark Streaming using Python, specifically textFileStream, and I've noticed a slightly weird behaviour. I was wondering if anybody could help explain this to me.

I currently have my code set up as follows:

```
def fileName(data):
    debug = data.toDebugString()
    pattern = re.compile("file:/.*\.txt")
    files = pattern.findall(debug)
    return files

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingFileNamePrinter")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

    lines = ssc.textFileStream("file:///test/input/")

    files = lines.foreachRDD(fileName)
    print(files)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The fileName function simple grabs the name of the file being processed from the debug stream ([Spark Streaming: How to get the filename of a processed file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853046/spark-streaming-how-to-get-the-filename-of-a-processed-file-in-python)). However, this code only runs once, printing files exactly once. When I modify the function as follows:

```
def fileName(data):
    debug = data.toDebugString()
    pattern = re.compile("file:/.*\.txt")
    files = pattern.findall(debug)
    print(files);
```

it checks the directory every second, as expected. It seems the only code that 'loops' is inside foreachRDD.

Am I correct in this assumption, and all processing (including loops, conditionals etc) must occur inside map functions and the like?

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DStream is composed of many rdds that are build over time.
lines is a DStream.

When you perform the foreachRDD on lines each rdd in your stream is transformed into a string. So when you print it you are getting a list of strings that represent all the rdds in the stream. Meaning, this happens "At the end of the stream".

When you print the string in the fileName function, you are doing it for each rdd in the stream while it is being proceed. So you are getting it while the stream is running.

Also, as I mentioned to you in your previous question, foreachRDD is not necessary here. It is not "The spark stream way" for this specific need and maybe this is why it confuses you.

The more direct way here is to use a map on the DStream itself (Which will effect all the rdd's in it) and then use pprint.

Remember that unlike a regular rdd, you can't just collect (Or anything similar) rdds in a stream and return the result while the stream is running. You need to do something with that data which will save it to some external source (If needed) or process it as part of the state of the whole stream.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.